# From c# call javascript function to call a map service with esri request

Tags: javascript, c#, arcgis-js-api

My question is about how to call this javascript function from c#, I use ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "EsriFunction", "esriservicecall();", true); to call this function from c# backend but it didnt work, i did not get the json data back. Anyone please help to solve this?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css"/>
 <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>
 function esriservicecall(){
 require([
    "esri/core/urlUtils",
    "esri/portal/Portal",
    "esri/identity/OAuthInfo",
    "esri/request"
  ], function(urlUtils, Portal, OAuthInfo, esriRequest) {
    var proxyURL =
      "xxxxxxx"; 

    var indexOfRules = urlUtils.addProxyRule({
      

      urlPrefix:
        "xxxxx", 
      proxyUrl: proxyURL
    });       

    // Define the 'options' for the request
    var options = {
      query: {
        f: "json",
        geometry: "109.742983, 1.6702204",
        geometryType:"esriGeometryPoint ",
        returnGeometry: false,
        inSR:4326,
        spatialRel:"esriSpatialRelWithin",
        units:"esriSRUnit_Foot ",
        outSR:4326,
        
      },
      responseType: "json"
    };

    // Make the request on a button click using the
    // value of the 'input' text

        var url = "https://gisdevportal.tnt.sarawak.gov.my/arcgis/rest/services/MOU_Shares_Layers_MIL1/MapServer/0/query";
      esriRequest(url, options).then(function(response) {
        console.log("response", response);
          var responseJSON = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
          document.getElementById('hid').value = responseJSON;
      });
    
 });
}
```

Comment: If that worked, it wouldn't be calling function from C#. You can't call the client like that from the server anyway. Why don't you just write the startup script as a proper piece of JavaScript?

Comment: This code work if i put in a proper piece of JavaScript. But i only want to call this function when backend c# needed. What you mean is i should try to put this into another JavaScript Html page, then call it when i need to use is it?

Comment: No I'm not suggesting that you create another page or anything like that. You are registering a startup script so I assumed you wanted it to run on startup. If you want it to run on demand based on a command issued from your server to the browser, you have to you something like signalr or something else that uses websockets. Clarify how you intend to call the function with an example

Comment: private string coordinatevalidation(string lon, string lat)
        {string location = lon + "," + lat;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "EsriFunction", "esriservicecall();", true);

return strresult;
        }

Comment: It just a simple method from code behind to call the function.

Comment: It would have helped if you said you were using aspx.

Comment: Anyway, that's not what register startup script does. It doesn't inject code into the page while it's running and then call it. What it does specify some JavaScript to execute when the page loads.

Comment: Yes. I was using aspx. So what is a proper way if i want to call that JavaScript function ?

Comment: You cannot call the client from the server. Ultimately, you have to set up a way for the client to ask the server when to call it, then the client will call it.